# XPath selecting a node with some attribute value equals to some other same level node's attribute value

Tags: xpath

```xml
<form-validation>
  <formset>
    <form name="BookForm"> ... </form>
    <form name="BookForm"> ... </form> <!-- This is what I want to locate -->
  </formset>

  <formset>
    <form name="BookForm"> ... </form> <!-- but not locate this line -->
  </formset>
</form-validation>
```

I want to locate the duplicated **form** element(**name** attribute value is the same as a previous one) in a **single formset**. How should I write the xPath expression?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.g. `//formset/form[@name = 'BookForm'][2]`.

In your comment you said you want to find the names of duplicates, in XPath 3.1 that is possible with e.g.

```
map:merge(//formset/form/map { string(@name) : . }, map { 'duplicates' : 'combine' }) => map:for-each(function($k, $v) { $k[$v[2]] })
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! but the value of the name attribute is unknown in advance. I need to find all duplicated forms. Then how to write it?

Comment: And you need/want to do that with solely XPath? Which version (there is 1.0 to 3.1)?

Comment: It seems that /form-validation/formset/form[@name=preceding-sibling::form/@name] can work!